# Is it preferred to use else or else-if for the final branch of a conditional

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, conventions

What's preferred

```
if n > 0
  # do something
elsif n == 0
  # do something
elsif n < 0
  # do something
end
```

or

```
if n > 0
  # do something
elsif n == 0
  # do something
else
  # do something
end
```

I was using `else` for awhile. I recently switched to doing `elsif`. My conclusions are the first option adds readability at the cost of more typing, but could confuse some people if they expect an `else`. I don't have enough experience to know if the first option would create more readability or more confusion and if there are other pros/cons I've missed.

For my specific example, where the scope of `else` is comparable to the previous conditions and what it does catch can be expressed as a simple condition, is using `else` preferable for the final branch? Also, would a different conditional influence the answer? I wrote the code in Ruby but I assume the answer is language agnostic. If it isn't, I would also like to know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know every execution path through your conditional logic regardless. That being said, a simple else for the remaining case is usually the most clear. If you only have an else if it makes the next guy scratch his head and wonder if you are missing something. If it makes you feel better to say "else what" then put an inline comment in `else # n < 0`

**edit after your edit:**

> For my specific example, where the scope of else is comparable to the previous conditions and what it does catch can be expressed as a simple condition, is using else preferable for the final branch? Also, would a different conditional influence the answer? I wrote the code in Ruby but I assume the answer is language agnostic. If it isn't, I would also like to know why.

Yes, else is still preferable. I can't think of any scenario that changes this answer. Having the else implies completeness in your logic. Not having the else will be distracting - others (or you at a later date) will have to spend more time scrutinizing the code to double check to make sure all conditions are being handled. In fact the coding standard I abide by, the *Embedded C Coding Standard* by BARR Group says this:

> "Any if statement with an else if clause shall end with an else clause. ... This is the equivalent of requiring a default case in every switch."

This echos [MISRA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISRA_C) rule 14.10

> All if ... else if constructs shall be terminated with an else clause.

*All of my examples pertain to C, but as you said in the post, this is someone agnostic to the language being used.

Comment: I don't agree with "You should know every execution path through your conditional logic regardless". Projects can be large and old code is often revisited. Knowing every execution path on all your code just isn't possible and/or feasible. Enhancing readability also allows other people to more easily understand your code. The rest of your answer and your documentation was really good though, thank you.

Comment: @Steve I said *should* and not *shall*. In a perfect world the answer is simple: refactor the code to a point where it is again easy to totally understand and easy to test. But because we don't always get to make those decisions, perhaps legacy code is an exception. But hopefully it is only a temporary exception. I can sympathize because I am the king of inheriting crufty cludgy spaghetti and meatballs code. But I still stand by what I said. A developer doing sustaining work on a code base he doesn't have a good grasp of is a particularly dangerous situation. ...

Comment: @Steve ... If any significant maintenance work is to be done on a cludgy code base it behooves the developer to try to convince the powers that be to budget time for refactoring. Going back to the example at hand. A switch construct with 500 cases might be a mess. It may take too long to fully explore it than the job at hand affords. But if time allows, this can generally be broken down into a jump table with function pointers. Then each case can be extracted into a short and testable/understandable function.

Comment: [Here is an example of replacing ugly nested switch statements with a jump table](http://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2014/03/replacing-nested-switches-with-multi-dimensional-arrays-of-pointers-to-functions/) - Again this is a C example, but hopefully the main idea is portable.

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer the plain `else` - it makes it obvious to anyone that your intention is "if all else fails, do this" (no pun intended).

In your example you only have 3 possible states, but what about if there were more?

Comment: More states wouldn't change the fundamental purpose of the example, would it?

Comment: I don't think I was clear, in this example there is no possible value that can be provided that wouldn't hit a branch of your if statement, but other examples there might be.  It's all a case of just indicating that if no other branch matches, do the else statement

Comment: I agree. I do think using `else` becomes more pertinent the more conditions it encompasses. I'll tune the question a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the final conditional statement to be a catch-all, then you should use just `else`. If you would like, for clarity, you could do something like this:

```
else # n < 0
   # do something
```

(Note the `n < 0` is just a comment). A couple reasons for this:

1. Depending on the language/compiler, there could be a speed improvement
2. Less likely to make a programming mistake. Your example above is fairly simple, but imagine a situation in which there is a fourth option that you did not consider at the time of programming? In that case, no action would be taken, when you probably meant for it to fall into the `else` statement.

Answer (score 1):

`else` creates a catch-all, with only `elsif`s none of the choices might be executed. Each specific situation needs its own solution, so I would use what is necessary.

Comment: Then I would prefer `else` because it more clearly shows that one of the blocks of code is always executed. Otherwise you would have to investigate the possible values of `n` to know that.

Answer (score 1):

`else` clarifies that it is the only branch of the program at that point. If the execution makes it there, no matter what it should go through the `else`. If that's your intention, use `else`, not `elseif` because although you can make the exact same program using `elseif` as the last statement, it sort of linguistically implies that it will only conditionally execute that block of code.